# ionic app extremely zoomed in after building

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, viewport

EDIT: I changed the viewport back to 1 and im gonna change the font sizes to how the size that should look the same. will update after i changed it all to see if it really works.

I tried alot of different things but it just doesnt show anything correctly. When I use ionic view it works perfectly and in browsers too.

viewport tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.3, maximum-scale=0.3, minimum-scale=0.3, user-scalable=no">
```

I ran the apk file on bluestacks and samsung galaxy s4 but the results i get looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMtLh.jpg

it should look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvA0v.jpg

I also tried to change the viewport to alot of different things and it didnt work.

Comment: Any reason you're using `0.3` as your viewport scale? Why not use `1`? This is probably the cause of your issues.

Comment: I was a bit lazy on the viewport changing it back to 1 because all my font sizes were wrong then. but now you mention it thats been the problem all along... I changed it back to 1 now and I changed the font size values to sizes that should work and now it works perfectly on my devices.. thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: My pleasure. Good luck! Will give you an 'official' answer as well ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is being caused by the `scale` you have set in your `viewport.`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.3, maximum-scale=0.3, minimum-scale=0.3, user-scalable=no">
```

The scale (initial only if you want to give the user an option to zoom in your app; if not, change maximum and minimum as well) should be set to `1` instead of `0.3`. Something along the lines of:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,  user-scalable=no">
```

make your initial scale property set to 1.0